# Register Variable in Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

Hi I'm new in Ansible and I'm having some problems using registered variables.

The problem is that I have multiple server with different operating systems.

I use roles to separate them, but in a case where there are no servers of one kind
a conditional gives me an error saying that I must put an expression that evaluates to True or False.

This is the code with the problem.

```
 - name: Checking if Sources are Available
   action: shell echo a$(cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep $(echo   'http://url/${ansible_distribution}/stable' | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"  ))
   register: sources
   ignore_errors: True

 - name: Adding source.
   action: shell echo "deb http://url/${ansible_distribution}/stable      ${ansible_lsb.codename} main" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   when: "ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and sources.stdout == 'a'"
```

The error that gives me is this one:

```
fatal: [192.168.1.114] => Conditional expression must evaluate to True or False: ({% if     ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and sources.stdout == 'a' %} True {% else %} False {% endif   %}) and ({% if ansible_os_family == 'Debian' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %})
fatal: [192.168.1.141] => Conditional expression must evaluate to True or False: ({% if ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and sources.stdout == 'a' %} True {% else %} False {% endif   %}) and ({% if ansible_os_family == 'Debian' %} True {% else %} False {% endif %})

 FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I already tried these ones:
   when: sources.stdout is defined and source.stdout == a
   only_if: sources.stdout is defined and source.stdout == a

And this gives me the same error.

I'm Using Ansible 1.3 in Ubuntu 13.04
To check this out I used ansible --version

Hope you can help me.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

i think this is related to this issue:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/3460

Seems to be fixed now in current dev version of ansible.

Answer (score 0):

I test the code use ansible 1.2 on my mbp, it works fine:

```
---
- hosts: local
  tasks:
    - name: Checking if Sources are Available
      action: shell echo a$(cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep $(echo   'http://url/${ansible_distribution}/stable' | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"  ))
      register: sources
      ignore_errors: True

    - debug: msg="sources value is ${sources.stdout} "
    - name: Adding source.
      action: shell echo "deb http://url/${ansible_distribution}/stable      ${ansible_lsb.codename} main" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
      when: "ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and sources.stdout == 'a'"
```

result:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [local] ******************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Checking if Sources are Available] *************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK: [debug msg="sources value is ${sources.stdout} "] ***********************
ok: [localhost] => {"msg": "sources value is a "}

TASK: [Adding source.] ********************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

you can refer to [official example:register_logic](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/register_logic.yml)

Answer (score -3):

Might it be that you have:

```
  gather_facts: false
```

in your playbook?